# SVN and VSS client on the same machine

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe, cruisecontrol

We have a working CruiseControl setup on a dedicated machine for project A. "A" uses VSS as its source code repository. Now, we would like to another project B to be handled by CruiseControl. "B" however, uses SVN as its source code repository.

A and B are not related, and point to source code repositories on different machines. They share nothing in common, except that they are managed by the same CruiseControl server.

Naturally, we have both VSS and SVN clients installed on the dedicated CruiseControl server. My question is this - will there be any issues with this kind of a setup - if there will be any conflicts due to both VSS and SVN clients on the same machine?

I know that theoretically, there will be NO problems, but I just want to confirm this.

Regards,
Ravi.

P.S.: Please do not post on why SVN is better than VSS and why we should switch. Our team already had a long-drawn debate on this. Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically, no. We've got SVN, VSS, and TFS all going on our machines at work with no problems whatsoever. Note: we do not use CruiseControl. Strictly in terms of using the three version control systems, I haven't had any issues other than Visual Studio being a little temperamental with knowing which plug-in to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Cory Larson mentioned above, there were no issues.

I am able to configure and use two independent projects - one from VSS and another from SVN with CruiseControl. Wanted to provide a confirmation in case it might be helpful to other people.

And btw, thanks Cory!